# Android game crashes when adding new view to view group programatically

Tags: android

I have been trying to add a new view to my view group for now I only have one view but I do want to add another one for buttons and things of that nature Here is the code for my Game View Class(View Group) :

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    public class GameView extends ViewGroup {

        private MainActivity activity;

        public GameView(Context context,MainActivity activity) throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            super(context);
            this.activity = activity;
            Graphics v = new Graphics(this,activity,context);
            addView(v);


        } 
        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean b, int i, int i2, int i3, int i4) {

        }
    }
```

This is the Code for my Graphics class :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Anonymous on 4/29/14.
 */

public class Graphics extends View implements Runnable,Button.OnTouchListener {
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    private Player p;
    private MainActivity activity;
    private Button b;
    GameView view;
    public Graphics(GameView view,MainActivity activity,Context context){
        super(context);
        this.view = view;
        this.activity = activity;
        p = new Player(400,600,activity);

    }

    public synchronized void start()
    {
        if(running)
            return;
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    public synchronized void stop()
    {
        if(!running)
            return;

        running = false;
        System.exit(0);

    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        while(running)
        {
            onDraw(c);
            tick();

        }

    }

    public void tick()
    {
        p.tick(this);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        try
        {
            p.render(canvas);

        }catch (IOException e)
        {

        }


    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent e){
        int action = e.getAction();
        switch(action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                p.setY(p.getY()+1);
                break;
        }


        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my main activity class :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        try{
        setContentView(new GameView(this,this));

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: Please post a stack trace from Logcat

Comment: There was none it was just blank

Comment: There is one. You may have your logcat filtered in such a way that the message is not being shown, but there is definitely a stack trace printed to logcat when an exception happens. Check your filters, make sure anything from your application can be shown. Reproduce the crash and check it.

Comment: Ok I will get right on that

Comment: I have changed it and still nothing it just says unfortunately the game has stopped no stacktrace at all

Comment: "unfortunately [...] has stopped" = logcat. Try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the logcat it's kind of risky to diagnose.

However

```
 private Player p;
```

is never initialized and used all over the place. So I'll venture you're getting NPE exceptions everywhere.

Comment: Wow I cant believe I didnt see that

Comment: it now doesent crash but the screen is white is there any way to fix that

Comment: This is just a guess, but personally, I'd try adding the view inside the activity itself, instead of inside the constructor of GameView

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Well I added the view group in the activity I have added the view itself in the activity before and it has worked but as I said above I want to have two views so I can have all my buttons on top of the bitmap image

Comment: So you tried something like aGameView.addView(v); inside of your Activity? I'm a little bit lost about what you're asking. What prevents you from adding different views multiple times from inside your activity? There is no limitation as to the number of Views that can be appended that way (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I will post my activity class so you can see what I mean

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I just posted my activity class maybe now you will see what I am trying to do

Comment: @user3000477 I know you're new around here, so in these cases you should: 1. Mark the answer as the correct one and 2. Open a new question to address the problem at hand.

Comment: @DigCamara Oh ok I wasn't aware of that will do next time , should I do that now?

Comment: if anyone can help here is the link to the new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393917/android-game-produces-blank-screen-when-i-add-new-view-to-view-group