# Android game produces blank screen when I add new view to view group

Tags: android

I am trying to have multiple views for my game so I created a view group and currently only have one and when I run the program I get a blank screen here is the code for my Game View Class(ViewGroup) :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class GameView extends ViewGroup {

    private MainActivity activity;

    public GameView(Context context,MainActivity activity) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        super(context);
        this.activity = activity;
        Graphics v = new Graphics(this,activity,context);
        addView(v);


    } 
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean b, int i, int i2, int i3, int i4) {

    }
}
```

here is my code for my graphics class(View) :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Anonymous on 4/29/14.
 */

public class Graphics extends View implements Runnable,Button.OnTouchListener {
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    private Player p;
    private MainActivity activity;
    private Button b;
    GameView view;
    public Graphics(GameView view,MainActivity activity,Context context){
        super(context);
        this.view = view;
        this.activity = activity;
        p = new Player(400,600,activity);

    }

    public synchronized void start()
    {
        if(running)
            return;
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    public synchronized void stop()
    {
        if(!running)
            return;

        running = false;
        System.exit(0);

    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        while(running)
        {
            onDraw(c);
            tick();

        }

    }

    public void tick()
    {
        p.tick(this);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        try
        {
            p.render(canvas);

        }catch (IOException e)
        {

        }


    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent e){
        int action = e.getAction();
        switch(action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                p.setY(p.getY()+1);
                break;
        }


        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting addView inside your Activity.

If you need to append a View more than once, just call addView more than once. Note that ViewGroup is an abstract class, so it may be quicker for you to simply use a LinearLayout to append your views to instead. LinearLayout is itself a ViewGroup.

Try out my suggestion, if you get stuck somewhere, please post the code of your new activity on here (please don't post your old activity), and tell us why you think you're getting stuck.

*For anyone else reading this, if you need more context, please see this [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392411/android-game-crashes-when-adding-new-view-to-view-group-programatically/23392697) that someone else asked him to split into two.*